# Is it better to create different tables for different stores or have one table with a column to designate which site

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am developing a mssql db for stores that are in different cities. is it better to have a table for each city, or house all in one table.  I also dont want users from different cities accessing data from cities that are not theirs

Comment: One table, with a column. The other solution is only going to make development and data extraction harder, not easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL is designed to handle large tables, really big tables.  It is not designed to handle a zillion little tables.  The clear answer to your question is that all examples of a particular entity should go in a single table.  There are lots of good reasons for this:

- You want to be able to write a query that will return data about any city or all cities.  This is easy if the data is in one table; hard if the data is in multiple tables.
- You want to optimize your queries by choosing correct indexes and data types and collecting statistics and defragging indexes and so on.  Why multiply the work by multiplying the number of tables?
- Foreign key relationships should be properly declared.  You cannot do that if the foreign key could be to multiple tables.
- Lots of small tables results in lots of partially filled data pages, which just makes the database bigger and slows it down.

I could go on.  But you probably get the idea by now that one table per entity is the right way to go (at least under most circumstances).

Your issue of limiting users to see data only in one city can be handled in a variety of ways.  Probably the most common is simply to use views.

Comment: Fantastic Response, thank you.  Having a stored proc that selects the appropriate view by passing in a "siteID" does sound like the best solution.